# Preserving order of dictionary while using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml for dumping a dict to a yaml file. While doing so, I want to keep the order of the dictionary. That is how I came across the question [Keep YAML file order with ruamel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849878/keep-yaml-file-order-with-ruamel). But this solution is not working in my case:

- The order is not preserved.
- adding tags like !!python/object/apply:ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap or dictitems

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap as ordereddict

generated_file = os.path.join('data_TEST.yaml')
data_dict = {'Sources': {'coil': None},  'Magnet': 'ABC', 'Current': ordereddict({'heat': {'i': [[]], 'h': None, }})}
data_dict = ordereddict(data_dict)

with open(generated_file, 'w') as yaml_file:
    ruamel.yaml.dump(data_dict, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

The used dictionary is just an arbitrary one and in the end an automatically created array that could look different is going to be used. So, we cannot hard-code the mapping of the dictionaries in the dictionary like in my example.

Result:

```
!!python/object/apply:ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap
dictitems:
  Current: !!python/object/apply:ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap
    dictitems:
      heat:
        h: null
        i:
        - []
  Magnet: ABC
  Sources:
    coil: null
```

Desired result:

```
Sources:
    coil: null
Magnet: ABC
Current:  
    heat:
    h: null
    i:
    - []
```

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really not be using the old PyYAML API that sorts keys when dumping.

Instantiate a YAML instance and use its dump method:

```
 yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
 yaml.dump(data, stream)
```

Comment: Then, the key default_flow_style=False also becomes obsolete, right?

Comment: Yes. Block style is the default, but you can change it using an attribute on the YAML instance.